# How to iterate through data and write to excel file quicker

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I have a pretty simple method that grabs data from an sql query and then puts it inside of a list and finally iterates through two for each loops onto an excel file. It works fine with small amounts of data, but not at all with larger amounts. What would be the best way to iterate and also write to my workbook the quickest?

Here is the code

```
  private UInt32 AddSheets(SpreadsheetDocument document, WorkbookPart workbookPart, Sheets sheets, string sheetName, UInt32 sheetNumber, List<RentalFeeReportingRecord> currentRecordList)
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> listofCoreBankingIds = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        listofCoreBankingIds = currentRecordList.Select(x => new { id = x.CoreBankingId, regionName = x.RegionName }).Distinct().ToDictionary(y => y.id, y => y.regionName);
        foreach (var coreBankingId in listofCoreBankingIds.OrderBy(x => x.Value))
        {

            WorksheetPart worksheetPart1 = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            string currentCurrency = null;
            string regionName = null;

            Worksheet worksheet1 = new Worksheet();
            SheetData sheetData1 = new SheetData();

            Row rowInSheet1 = new Row();
            Row firstRow = new Row();
            Row lastRow = new Row();

            rowInSheet1.Append(
              excelController.ConstructCell("Region", CellValues.String, 3), excelController.ConstructCell("Merchant - Terminal", CellValues.String, 3),
              excelController.ConstructCell("Fee Charged", CellValues.String, 3),
              excelController.ConstructCell("Currency", CellValues.String, 3),
              excelController.ConstructCell("Processing Date", CellValues.String, 3),
              excelController.ConstructCell("Description", CellValues.String, 3)
            );

            sheetData1.Append(rowInSheet1);


            foreach (var currentRecord in currentRecordList.OrderBy(x => x.RegionName).ThenBy(z => z.Currency).ThenBy(y => y.DateProcessed))
            {
                if (coreBankingId.Key == currentRecord.CoreBankingId)
                {

                    regionName = currentRecord.RegionName;
                    currentCurrency = currentRecord.Currency;
                    double currentTotal = currentRecord.TotalFeeAmount;
                    string merchant = currentRecord.MerchantRecord.MerchantID + " - " + currentRecord.MerchantTerminalRecord.terminalID;

                    if (currentRecord.IsPinPad)
                    {
                        merchant = merchant + " - PIN Pad";
                    }

                    string description = currentRecord.TerminalRecord.description;
                    if (currentRecord.IsProRated)
                    {
                        int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(currentRecord.DeployedDate.Year, currentRecord.DeployedDate.Month);

                        description = currentRecord.TerminalRecord.description + " (" + currentRecord.MonthlyFee + " Fee \\ " + days.ToString() + " Days) * " + currentRecord.DaysActive.ToString() + " Days Active";
                    }

                    rowInSheet1 = new Row();
                    firstRow = new Row();
                    lastRow = new Row();

                    rowInSheet1.Append(
                      excelController.ConstructCell(regionName, CellValues.String, 2),
                      excelController.ConstructCell(merchant, CellValues.String, 2),
                      excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.TotalFee.ToString("N2"), CellValues.String, 1),
                      excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.Currency, CellValues.String, 2),
                      excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.DateProcessed.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy"), CellValues.String, 2),
                      excelController.ConstructCell(description, CellValues.String, 2)
                    );

                    sheetData1.Append(rowInSheet1);

                }

            }


            Columns columns = excelController.AutoSize(sheetData1);

            worksheet1.AppendChild(columns);
            worksheet1.AppendChild(sheetData1);
            worksheetPart1.Worksheet = worksheet1;


            Sheet sheet1 = new Sheet()
            {

                Id = document.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart1),
                SheetId = sheetNumber,
                Name = regionName
            };

            sheets.Append(sheet1);
            sheetNumber++;
        }
        return sheetNumber;

    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: StackOverflow is not for "code that works but needs to be made quicker" - see codereview.stackexchange.com / profile your code and see where it spends most of its time

Comment: ps; if it fails and gives an error message on larger amounts, post the error message and line number. questions that ask "what is the best" are usually off topic because they require an opinionated answer; if you can address these issues this question might become in topic for SO